# Use all images from my default store on my new store view

Tags: product, php, product-images, ee-1.13, mage-shell

I have a new store view and i've updated all the products using the

**magento admin: Manage Products > Select all > Update Attributes**

and then selecting the new store. Now that all my products are affiliated with my new store view i'm having a problem with all my images. On the front end it shows all placeholders. In the admin panel when i click on a product and then images.. it may have images but it's not selected to use base image, small image or thumbnail.

Is there a way to update all images on my new store view to use the default store view main images?

```
require_once 'abstract.php';

class Attach_Default_Store_Images Extends Mage_Shell_Abstract {

    public function run()
    {
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $productFrom = $product->setStoreId(1)->getImage();
            $productTo = $product->setStoreId(13)
            ->setImage($productFrom)
            ->setSmallImage($productFrom)
            ->setThumbnail($productFrom);
            echo "Images Updated\n";
            $product->save();
   }

        Mage::getModel('catalog/product_image')->clearCache();
        echo "Image Cache Cleared\n";

    }


    public function usageHelp()
    {
        return <<<USAGE
Usage:  php -f cache.php -- [options]
        php -f cache.php -- clean

  clean             Clean Old Cache
  help              This help

USAGE;
    }
}

$shell = new Attach_Default_Store_Images();
$shell->run();
```

Run a shell script with above?

Comment: When You select store radio button selected or not ?

Comment: Hi @PrashantBarot, could you please elaborate on what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

One solution could be to delete the entries directly in the Database.
In the table `catalog_product_entity_varchar` you can find all images with the associated `store_id`. If there is no entry with a specific `store_id`, Magento will use the value with the `store_id` 0 (Default StoreView)

With this Query you see all Images which are set in a StoreView

```
SELECT
    attributes.entity_id, attributes.store_id, attributes.value,  eav.attribute_code
FROM
    catalog_product_entity_varchar attributes
    JOIN eav_attribute eav ON attributes.attribute_id = eav.attribute_id
WHERE 
    eav.attribute_code IN ("image", "small_image", "thumbnail") 
    AND attributes.store_id > 0
```

What the Query does is, it selects all default image attributes `image`, `small_image` and `thumbnail` with a store_id bigger then 0.
I used the `eav_attribute` table to select all entries with the attribute codes, because sometime the IDs are different.

The Result looks like this (in your case its a bigger list):

```
entity_id   store_id   value            attribute_code
86          6          /i/a/iamge1.png  image
86          6          /i/a/iamge2.png  small_image
86          6          /i/a/iamge2.png  thumbnail
```

Now we can test if this works like expected. If we choose a Product ID (entity_id) and change the images in the adminpanel to `Use Default Value` and execute the Query again, the entries are removed from the table

So, we can convert this select Query into a delete Query

```
DELETE FROM 
    attributes.entity_id, attributes.store_id, attributes.value,  eav.attribute_code
FROM
    catalog_product_entity_varchar attributes
    JOIN eav_attribute eav ON attributes.attribute_id = eav.attribute_id
WHERE 
    eav.attribute_code IN ("image", "small_image", "thumbnail") 
    AND attributes.store_id > 0
```

> **Before executing the delete query on your production system, you should test it on a test system.**

In the case you want to change it for a specific StoreView, just change the `WHERE` clause to

```
AND attributes.store_id = 12 //Your StoreView ID
```

Comment: I'm not really using to use a sql query rather run a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your attributes panel, find the image/small image/thumbnail attributes.
Note down the ids (mine in this case were 85,86 and 87)
Change the query to reflect those id's.
So my query looks like:

```
Delete FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id IN (85,86,87) AND store_id > 0;
```